# How To Reboot a PC inside snap app (created with Flutter) on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: snap, reboot

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 on my PC, and also i have a **snapped** Linux app that created with Flutter. I have also a button for rebooting the OS in my Flutter app.

I tried two different methods:

**method 1:**

```
await Process.run("reboot", []);
```

message:

```
flutter: Running in chroot, ignoring request.
```

**method 2:**

```
await Process.run('sudo', ['reboot']);
```

message:

```
flutter: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 54 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 54
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Also this is my 'snapcarft.yaml' file content:

```
name: panel-gyro-compass
version: 1.0.0
summary: panel gyro compass
description: panel gyro compass

confinement: strict
base: core18
grade: stable


slots:
  dbus-panel-gyro-compass: # adjust accordingly to your app name
    interface: dbus
    bus: session
    name: org.bar.panel_gyro_compass # adjust accordingly to your app name and


    
apps:
  panel-gyro-compass:
    command: panel_gyro_compass
    extensions: [flutter-master] # Where "master" defines which Flutter channel to use for the build
    plugs: [network, serial-port]
    slots: [dbus-panel-gyro-compass]

parts:
  panel-gyro-compass:
    source: .
    plugin: flutter
    flutter-target: lib/main.dart # The main entry-point file of the application
```

please show me how to run a command in Flutter for Rebooting the PC.

Comment: Snaps are containerised to prevent them from having too much access to the computer. You would need to be running the Snap as a traditional application to do this, which sort of defeats the purpose of wrapping the program in a Snap 

Comment: It requires access to systemd via dbus. See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/system-reboot-from-within-a-strictly-confined-snap/10080, where reboot from within a snap is explained by the developers.